# Adding social share buttons for individual images on a web page

Tags: images, sharing

I am looking for a way to add social share buttons (Facebook, Twitter and Pintrest) for all individual images on a given web page.

Here is an example: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_life.html

As you can see in the above URL, each image has its own share buttons.

Is there a simple way to achieve this for a Wordpress blog post?

Thank you!

Comment: Found this on reddit today - http://fiv5r.com/reviews/add-social-sharing-icon-wordpress-images.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin from Addthis:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/